# C++ take a letter from a file

Tags: c++, if-statement, input, output, fstream

I'm working on a C++ file. And this is what I've got: The user has to type the name of a file, e.g. file1.txt, and I have to count the letters in that file. 
All of this is working but: after "x" letters, I have to take the next letter and show it on the screen. I don't really know how to do this?

I think it has to be an if-statement and it has to start like this:
if (count_letters = x){
} 
But I'm really lost after that.

Thanks !

Comment: What code have you tried? Stack overflow helps you with code problems, not tells you what code to write!

Comment: Not true. Stackoverflow handles questions about programming. This does not necessarily mean "write code". However when the OP asks about code, then he/she should provide some samples (if he/she has any).

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if (count_letters >= x)
```

Note that the `==` operator compares two values, whilst `=` assigns a value to a variable. Then in your if body you'd probably just do something along the lines of

```
std::cout << letters[x] << std::endl;
```

Comment: No, it should be ```>=``` - Are you trying to get Melissa an 'F'?

Comment: @user3791372 Oops, you're right. Not an F, just a D-. :)